# Como passar estruturas para funções de classes de gabaritos

Tags: c++, classes, template

Eu simplesmente não entendo porque esta errado.
Este código funciona.

```
template
class test{
public:
    struct st1{
        T a, b, c;
    };
    struct st2{
        T d, e, f;
    };

    T foo1(st1 *st);
    st1 *foo2();
};

template
typename test::st1 *foo2()
{
    return 0;
}

template
T test::foo1(typename st1 *st)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Mas este não funciona.

```
template
class test{
public:
    struct st1{
        T a, b, c;
    };
    struct st2{
        T d, e, f;
    };

    T foo1(st1 *st);
    st1 *foo2();
    st1 *foo3(st2 *st);
};

template
T test::foo1(typename st1 *st)
{
    return 0;
}

template
typename test::st1 *foo2()
{
    return 0;
}

template
typename test::st1 *foo3(typename st1 *st)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sinceramente, eu não acredito que qualquer um funcione http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6f47cd72c94782b

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe do seu segundo código está completamente errada.

```
template <typename T>
class test{
public:
    struct st1{
        T a, b, c;
    };
    struct st2{
        T d, e, f;
    };

    T foo1(st1 *st);
    st1 *foo2();
    st1 *foo3(st2 *st);
};

template <typename T>T test<T>::foo1(st1 *st)
{
    return 0;
}

template <typename T> typename test<T>::st1* test<T>::foo2()
{
    return 0;
}

template <typename T> typename test<T>::st1* test<T>::foo3(st2 *st)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Esta é a sintaxe correta, mas gostaria de saber o que exatamente você espera conseguir com esta classe. Você está estudando templates?